# How were improvised masks used to defend gas attacks in World War One?

Tags: world-war-one, chemicals

During the battle for Ypres in April 1915 the attacking Germans used chlorine gas to great effect, nearly annihilating the 1,100 defending French. The French had moved closer to the gas cloud, assuming it was a veil of smoke, and sustained near total casualties - leaving a kilometer wide gap in their defensive trenchworks. After the French had perished the attackers failed to fully capitalize on the gap and Canadian troops were able to fend off the approaching Germans, using urine-soaked rags as makeshift gas masks. ([source - 1:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHvaLDe-xiY))

The chlorine gas dissolves in water, and any cloth soaked in water, coffee, or urine would have provided defense against the new weapon. Of course, the Canadian soldiers couldn't have known this at the time - they thought the ammonia in urine would dissolve the chemical agent. After the use of gas at Ypres how quickly were gas masks made into a standard part of a soldier's kit, and before that point how was the use of improvised masks enforced? Did soldiers keep a supply of urine or were other fluids perceived as safe in the event of a chlorine gas attack?

Comment: I fear this question is too broad, between the question "how widespread was the use of improvised masks", versus "what was the process of improvising a mask (beyond just urination - were there prerequisites?)", versus "how long did it take supply gas masks to the front line" If anyone has suggestions on how to *cleanly* narrow this down I'm receptive. I've tried for the last twenty minutes.

Comment: At least partial answers to your questions can be found in [Chemical Weapons in World War I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_weapons_in_World_War_I) (see 'Effectiveness and countermeasures') and [Second Battle of Ypres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Battle_of_Ypres) (see 'Battle of St. Julien' and the paragraph just above it). You will probably find it easier to refine your question after reading these. Hope these help.

Comment: A correlated question is "which kind of masks had the german troops using this gas for the first time" ?